# Could "subtracting infinity" in renormalization be characterized as an operation in transfinite arithmetic?

Tags: quantum-information, mathematical-physics, renormalization

Inasmuch as extracting roots is iterated division (is it? I don't actually know for sure!) and division can be iterated subtraction, is it possible to describe renormalization in, say, quantum information theory, as "the computer of the universe" (please forgive that turn of phrase) taking some (the aleph-zeroth?) root of the Continuum to yield the discrete level of infinity (aleph-zero)?

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? It isn't clear what you are asking so more detail would  help. I have the impression that your question would be more suitable on Philosophy SE.

Answer (score 2):

I see no useful way to express renormalization in terms of transfinite math (let alone as the taking of a transfinite root). It really is fundamentally about finite quantities, not infinite ones. Perhaps read about "Wilsonian renormalization" to understand this.